# HAProxy for Redis Sentinel: want BACKUP, not DOWN

Tags: haproxy, redis, redis-sentinel

I configured an HAProxy service for my Redis Cluster installation (3 nodes with Redis Sentinel managing the master delegation) and it works good: clients are redirected only to the master node and whenever a slave node becomes master, HAProxy suddenly change the active member into the backend.

Just wanting to be meticulous, the slave nodes are shown as **"DOWN" (red colour)** into the HAProxy Statistics Report **(Layer7 timeout: at step 5 of tcp-check (expect string 'role:master'))**. Is there a way to have them shown as **"backup UP" (blue colour)**, which is the correct definition?

This because red nodes seems to be a problem, but this is not true as slave members are UP but they are just slave so they are not active. I think this is the correct definition of the "backup UP" state into HAProxy.

This is the configuration of HAProxy:

```
frontend Redis
    bind            192.168.70.90:6379 name 192.168.70.90:6379   
    mode            tcp
    log         global
    timeout client      30000
    default_backend     Redis_tcp_ipvANY

backend Redis_tcp_ipvANY
    mode            tcp
    timeout connect     30000
    timeout server      30000
    retries         3
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check connect
    tcp-check send PING\r\n
    tcp-check expect string +PONG
    tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
    tcp-check expect string role:master
    tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
    tcp-check expect string +OK
    server          redis1 192.168.70.91:6379 check inter 1000  maxconn 1024 
    server          redis2 192.168.70.92:6379 check inter 1000  maxconn 1024 
    server          redis3 192.168.70.93:6379 check inter 1000  maxconn 1024
```

Do you have any idea about how it's possible to do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the health check for the backup node is coming back as up?

Comment: Yes, if I shutdown the master node one of the slave nodes becomes master and HAProxy makes it UP and green into the statistic page.

Comment: You have designed a health check that ensures that non-master nodes will **fail**  the health check because `tcp-check expect string role:master`.

Comment: Yes, I understand this and I understand that HAProxy is working good. But I am wondering if there is any way to tell HAProxy to consider nodes which not have `string role:master` as BACKUP and not as DOWN.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but as you have more than two nodes, **IT WON'T FAIL OVER CORRECTLY**. But since you asked:

```
backend Redis_tcp_ipvANY
    mode            tcp
    timeout connect     30000
    timeout server      30000
    retries         3
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check connect
    tcp-check send PING\r\n
    tcp-check expect string +PONG
    tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
    tcp-check expect string +OK
    server          redis1 192.168.70.91:6379        inter 1000  maxconn 1024 check
    server          redis2 192.168.70.92:6379 backup inter 1000  maxconn 1024 check
    server          redis3 192.168.70.93:6379 backup inter 1000  maxconn 1024 check
```

The haproxy `BACKUP` state simply means the server won't be considered for load-balancing as long as any normal server is `UP`. Your present setup is better, I think.

Comment: Why it will not failover correctly?

Comment: Because failover traffic will possibly go to backend that is not of `role:master` (there is one master, but you have two backups).